# Solving linear programming problem with mixed type of constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I have a query in solving the problem below:

**An automobile company has two factories. One factory has 400 cars (of a certain model)
in stock and the other factory has 300 cars (of the model) in stock. Two customers order
this car model. The first customer needs 200 cars, and the second customer needs 300 cars.
The cost of shipping cars from the two factories to the customers is shown:**

|  | Customer 1 | Customer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Factory 1 | \$ 30 | \$ 25 |
| Factory 2 | \$ 36 | \$ 30 |

**How should the company ship the cars in order to minimize the shipping cost?**

I am confused about how to proceed with this problem. I have considered the slack variables $x_3$ through $x_6$, and conversion of the minimisation problem to a maximisation one, and got:

$\text{Maximise Z}=6x_1+5x_2-16200$
$\text{subject to, }x_1+x_2+x_3=400$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~-x_1-x_2+x_4=-200$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_1+x_5=200$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_2+x_6=300$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6 \ge 0$

However, when I start with the dual simplex method, I cannot get an entering variable, since the $C_j-Z_j$ values of the first iteration are all $\gt 0$.
How do I solve this using simplex and/or dual simplex? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not really a CS question, is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to transform this into normal form. Depending on how you learned it, you need to transform all constraints to the form $a\ge b$, or $a\le b$, where in $a$ you have variables and in $b$ only constants.

Transform $=$ into $\le$ and $\ge$ and from there you can easily transform this into normal form

Comment: I have already converted all constraints into $\le$ form and have added the slack variables. What I have written in the question is simply the set of equations I have got after performing preliminary calculations on the original LPP

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the algorithm you are using?

Comment: I am using the dual simplex method as explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrcEdYebchw

Answer (score 0):

You always need an initial solution. If you don't have one, you create another problem to get the initial solution.

In your case: Imagine you don't ship enough cars. Customer 1 misses $x_7$ and customer 2 misses $x_8$ cars. So you change two equations : $x_1 + x_5 + x_7 = 200$, $x_2 + x_6 + x_8 = 300$. And this has an initial solution: $x_1 = x_5 = x_2 = x_6 = 0$, $x_7 = 200$, $x_8 = 300$. And you find the minimum for $x_7 + x_8$. If the minimum is > 0, then your original problem has no solution. If the minimum is 0, then you drop $x_7$ and $x_8$ and you just have found a (non-optimal) solution for the initial problem.

(I don't know if it is 100% correct, but the idea is that you create variables that express exactly how "wrong" your solution is, the initial value is "completely wrong", and you minimise the wrongness. If the minimal wrongness is zero, you have a starting point for the original problem, otherwise there is no solution).

PS. What if there is no solution? You can tell people there is no solution, but that isn't really helpful because the solution should tell people what action to take.

In that case you could say "Customers will be angry if they don't get their cars, and we add an annoyance factor of \$200 for each car that customer 1 doesn't get, and \$300 for each car that customer 2 doesn't get. Now we have a problem with a solution. We may not like the solution, but it will be the best we can get". And people can act on the solution.